# Playwrite Recommendation on Language It Supports

Tags: playwright

We know playwright supports multiple languages node js/java/.net/python, when we are doing analysis in playwright we got to know some of the features are not available in java version and available only in node js.

Is there any recommendation from playwright in terms of choosing language/ more priority on specific lang

Answer (score 1):

I think it's a subjective question based on couple of primary context variables:

1. **Development Ecosystem**: If you can stay in same techstack as the  dev team that is helpful for code sharing and  other purposes.Using the overall same ecosystem simplifies alot particularly in the pipelines.
2. **Comfortablity of test team with specific language and its ecosystem**- I think that matters a lot as they will be developing & maintaining it down the line.
3. And  Yes , **nodeJs version is mostly ahead in terms of features** compared to other languages , as per my observation as well.

So I think overall it depends on  project and team context with various trade-offs.